# Restrict access to device settings

Tags: settings, password

How can I prevent people who borrow my device from changing any of my settings?

Answer (score 1):

App locker more :

1. [Smart App Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sp.protector.free&hl=en)
2. [Advanced Protection](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applockwatcher&hl=en)
3. [Apps Lock & Gallery Hider](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mig.app.gallery&hl=en)
4. [App Lock (Pattern)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwego.applock.pattern&hl=en)

Comment: App Lockers doesn't block access to Settings completely... They could still open it from the Notifications Tab...