# how to password protect settings dialog (wifi but specifically accounts part)?

Tags: settings, password

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restrict access to device settings](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8536/restrict-access-to-device-settings)

I would like to disable the settings page so that users of our android devices cannot factory reset through settings and cannot use another account for buying or installing items from google play marketplace. Probably an app on google play would be best for this unless anyone has an idea.

Note: we are a school system so this is necessary to be CIPA complaint and teenagers can be an IT nightmare sometimes. Also, this is an lenovo tablet device so instructions might be different.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Restrict access to device settings](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/8536)

Comment: You should post another app or suggestion below in case the linked to thread does not apply in my situation. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: link is dead for suggested app from other thread. So that thread does not apply.

Comment: The fact that the link in the answer is dead doesn't mean that this question is different from that one (and the link has been fixed now). If the other question doesn't apply because your needs are different then perhaps you could explain that a bit more. Right now it is not evident.

Comment: Okay well I will check out the link if its fixed.

Comment: okay it fixed thanks for the link you can mark that as answer to prevent other answerers if you wish